# Python, как из переменной забрать первые 3, 5, 7 строк текста

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть переменная которая может содержать текст, по типу:

```
This is good day. 
Это хороший день.
    
Tomorrow, we will to do something
Завтра мы будем делать что-то

n*
```

или

```
This is good day.
Tomorrow, we will to do something
n*
```

Количество строк всегда неизвестно и может доходить до нескольких десятков. Подскажите каким образом из переменной можно забрать определённое количество первых строк, например первых 6 строк. Не могу найти примера, чтобы самостоятельно разобраться.

Comment: `"\n".join(text.splitlines()[:6])`

Comment: @Danis спасибо, именно то что нужно! Тем кто не понял, за место text прописываете свою переменную и прописываете код от Danis для другой переменной. Например: en_word = "\n".join(text.splitlines()[:6])